が VS は in the sentence pattern: (general event) のは / のが、(time coordinate) だ
In the pattern: (general event) のは / のが、(time coordinate) だ, what determines which one gets chosen? Let's consider the following excerpt from Episode 198 (marked as JLPT N4 level) of the "Let's Talk Japanese" podcast:
桜は皆さん知っていますよね。日本の春の花です。この桜はだいたい暖かいところだと、三月の終わりぐらいに咲き始めて、あ、違うか、咲き始めるのはちょっと早いか。三月の真ん中ぐらいかな、早いところだと。そして、「満開」と言って、その木の花が全部咲く、それが早いところだと三月の終わりぐらい。遅いところ – 寒いところは遅いんですけど – 遅いところだと、桜が咲き始めるのがたいたい四月の最初ぐらいですね。そして、桜が満開になるのがだいたい四月の真ん中ぐらい。で、卒業式は三月にするので、卒業式というと、桜のイメージが強いです。
Instinctively, my go-to choice would be to use のは in all three cases marked in bold, maybe because that's the pattern I hear more often.
I am aware of this question. In the second answer to it, Aguijonazo said:

Suppose someone is introducing a sports team or something, and that
person says:
（このチームは）キャプテンが田中さんです。
This wouldn’t sound particularly odd to me even if I hadn’t heard of
Tanaka-san before. I would only expect something like 副キャプテンが山下さんです to
follow.
I think キャプテン here can be seen as one of a number of aspects of the
topic, which in this case is the team Tanaka-san is the captain of,
and therefore, the above sentence can be understood as describing
something (チーム) focusing on a particular aspect of it (キャプテン). The
particle が may be used to exclude other aspects (e.g. 副キャプテン) for
better focus. I cannot explain why, but I feel the aspect to be
focused with が has to be picked from a limited set, rather than an
open-ended one.

Could it be that this explanation also applies to the excerpt above? Just like I could be listing  roles in a team assigning a player to each role, here the podcaster is listing stages of the blooming of sakuras assigning time coordinates to each stage?

Yes, I believe the second answer by aguijonazo explains the phenomenon in your text, too. I feel this has something to do with the fact that many seasons in a mental "list" are being introduced.
は and が can be used pretty much interchangeably in contexts like these:

チームを紹介します。田中さんがディレクターで、佐藤さんがプログラム、鈴木さんはデザインを担当します。高橋さんはローカライズ担当、山田さんが広報担当です。
彼が帰ってきたのは3日前、また大阪に戻っていったのが2日前で、最後に電話をくれたのが今朝のことです。
バナナは果物で、ナシも果物、キャベツは野菜でナスも野菜です。ゴボウが野菜、メロンが果物、キノコがどっちでもない感じで、リンゴやイチゴは果物で……

These texts remain perfectly valid and natural if は is used consistently, but I even feel that using both of the two leads to more vivid and less monotonous sentences.
His second answer suggests that the reason が can be used is that there is a big topic like "how to classify food" in the speaker's mind. I think this can be correct, but I'm also interested in whether there's any research on this phenomenon.
